# How To Send Background Worker Information To Another Computer In C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

So I am writing a client/server program, which the client will listen for a command from the server program. I have the two able to find each other on the network with their ip addresses. Essentially, the server program has a background worker with code that I want to send to the client machine to run. Is there a way to do this?

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AILocker
{
    public partial class HiveMind : Form
    {
        public HiveMind()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {
                try
                {
                    IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(ipv4.Text); //use local m/c IP address, and use the same in the client

                    /* Initializes the Listener */
                    TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

                    /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
                    myList.Start();

                    MessageBox.Show("The server is running at port 8001...");
                    MessageBox.Show("The local End point is  :" + myList.LocalEndpoint);
                    MessageBox.Show("Looking for other computer");

                    Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
                    Console.WriteLine("Found buddy " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

                    byte[] b = new byte[100];
                    int k = s.Receive(b);
                    Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
                    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

                    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
                    s.Send(MainForm.googlesearch.RunWorkerAsync());
                    Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
                    /* clean up */
                    
                    s.Close();
                    myList.Stop();

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not find other computer.");
                }

            }

        }

        private void ipv4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Listener
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

                tcpclnt.Connect(RecieveIP.Text, 8001); // use the ipaddress as in the server program

                MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

                String str = Console.ReadLine();
                Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

                ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
                MessageBox.Show("Transmitting.....");

                stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

                byte[] bb = new byte[100];
                int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

                for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                    Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

                tcpclnt.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not find server computer.");
            }
        }

        private void RecieveIP_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The issue running into is that googlesearch.runworkerasync is unsendable due to its protection level, is there a way to send the code of the backroundworker listed above to be run by the client computer? Thank you.

Comment: You want the server to send *code* to the client computer, not data? As in, the server will send a string of code like `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");`, the client will receive it, compile it into an exe and run the exe?

Comment: If a server could send arbitrary code to a client and make it execute it, there would be a serious security problem. Your server can't tell your client what to do. What is typically done is the server sends *data* and the client reads it and does something in response. But the actual executable code that is running has to be on the client.

Comment: What I am trying to do. When the client receives a connection confirmation, run code that I will put in the client. Thank you. I am also wondering, is there a way for the client and server to automatically find find each other on the network? Thank you

Comment: How are you going to solve environmental problems? (Your attempt is very dangerous!)

Comment: I will add the code to the background worker. But will add several background workers, so how can I have it so the client will run a certain background worker depending on what button is clicked on the server? Thanks.